# Updating and Saving in a Single Query in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to update a parent table and simultaneously save data in child table in a single custom query in hibernate.
This is my serviceimplementation.

```
public int updateTimeTable(Map<String, Object> timeTable) {
    int rows = timeTableDao.updateTimeTable(timeTable);
    if(rows>2) {
        rows = temptimeTableDao.updateTempTimeTable(timeTable);
    }
    return rows;
}
```

This are the query files(save customQuery):

```
public int updateTempTimeTable(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Query query = customQuery("Insert into temp_time_table(employee_id,duration_till,duration_from,timetable_id)"
            + " values(:employeeId, :durationStart,:durationEnd,:timetableId)");
    query.setLong("employeeId", Long.parseLong(map.get("employeeId").toString()));
    query.setString("durationStart", map.get("durationStart").toString());
    query.setString("durationEnd", map.get("durationEnd").toString());
    query.setLong("timetableId", Long.parseLong(map.get("timetableId").toString()));

    return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

updateTimeTable query:

```
public int updateTimeTable(Map<String, Object> map) {
    if (map.isEmpty() && !map.containsKey("id"))
        return 0;
        String hql = "update TimeTable set ";
        int count = 0;
        String status = null;
        if (map.containsKey("status") && map.get("status") != null) {
            hql += "status = :status";
            status = map.get("status").toString();
            count++;
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        hql += " where id = " + map.get("id");
        Query query = update(hql);
        if (status != null) {
            query.setString("status", status);
        }

        return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: You can try with a simple query, something like below,
update tableName set name='MRK' where id=1
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
   insert into test(name) values('USER');

Comment: The parentId in child table will be updated only through URL fired otherwise the child table will remain empty. What I want is while updating the parentTable(column:status) the values in child table should be inserted then only

Comment: I am not following you requirement. DO you mean when you persist a column in a parent object and only if success then insert the same row into child table ??

Comment: Yes but with a slight difference that I want to insert new values in the child table

Comment: Did you try the query that I shared for your requirement? That should work, it should not be an issue with the new values

Comment: I am getting this as an error: antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: TemporaryTimeTable